# How to use onCodeSubmitted effectively so the login button is clickable only after the OTP is autofilled in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter Application, I have otp screen on which there's a login button. After the otp is automatically filled, user clicks login and a loader appears and user is logged in. But what if user clicks login before the otp is filled. I want to handle this situation. My approach is to use onCodeSubmitted function provided in PinFieldAutoField
Widget. What I did was

```
child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                                        onCodeSubmitted: (p0) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            showLogin = true;
                                          });
                                        },
                                        codeLength: 6,
                                      )),
```

I made a variable that becomes true after code is submitted. Ater this i have a ternary operator that shows clickable button only when showLogin variable is true. Initially its false so its unclickable button ie nothing happens if u click it.
I think my onCodeSubmitted is wrong because clickable button is not appearing after otp is filled on the screen. Can I do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onCodeChanged` to input data and then enable the button by comparing the length of pin.

```dart
  String pin = ""; // state variable,outside the build method
```

```dart
PinFieldAutoFill(
  onCodeChanged: (p0) {
    setState(() {
      pin = p0 ?? "";
    });
  },
),
ElevatedButton(
  // default length is 6
  onPressed: pin.length < 6 ? null : () {},
  child: Text("login"),
)
```